# Как проверить SSD на выделенном сервере под Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, диск, ssd

Есть арендованный выделенный сервер с одним SSD на 512ГБ под управлением Ubuntu 16.04. Арендую уже около полугода. Нагрузка на диск постоянная. Ни минуты покоя. Хостер при установке говорил, что скорее всего диск новый.

Как не удаляя данные и останавливая запущенные процессы, проверить диск на наличие плохих секторов?

Как по результатам проверки понять, что диск желательно менять?

Comment: на ssd не может быть в работе плохих секторов, может только кончится запас хороших, для проверки есть smartctl

Comment: ssd проверяется только фирменными утилитами от производителя, которые обычно доступны только под винду. Умрёт-не умрёт - вообще не важно, если ты делаешь бэкапы. Если не делаешь - мне тебя искренне жаль.

Comment: @PavelGridin, smart не показатель. А тем более на ssd.